# Confusion over changing the bounds of an iterated integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

I have the following:

> The sum of the iterated integrals $$ \int_{-2}^{-1}\int_{-\sqrt{y+2}}^{\sqrt{y+2}} f(x,y)\, dx\, dy + \int_{-1}^{2}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{y+2}} f(x,y)\, dx\, dy$$ is equal to:

a) $\int_{-1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{x^2+1}^{x-1} f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$

b) $\int_{-1}^{2}\int_{x^2-2}^{x} f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$

c) $\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{2}\int_{x^2-2}^{x} f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$

d) $\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{x^2+2}^{x} f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$

e) $\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{x^2+2}^{x} f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$

I'm not sure how to combine the sums to be honest. The answer isn't choice D. If this was a single integral, I can change the bounds more easily, but with something like this, I am not so sure... I assume the bounds are in some kind of circle but I am not sure.

How do I combine this to a single integral?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of the plane region you are integrating over?

Comment: I ASSUME it's a circle but I am not sure...

Comment: What do you get, when you solve for $y$ from the bounds $x=\pm\sqrt{y+2}$ of the inner integral of the first term?

Comment: Well that gives me a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$. In other words, $x^2+y^2=2$.

Comment: Oops yes you are right. That was my mistake. Okay. Let me take another crack at this.